# Reallocate some free space to another partition

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I'm at the moment in this situation:

[image: from Gparted on Ubuntu LiveCd]

and I'd like to take likely 10GB from `/dev/sda1` and add them to `/dev/sda3`

is it possible without damaging other partitions? It's like an hour I'm struggling with Gparted and looking form some hints on the net without success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested actions:

- Shrink the SDA1 primary partition by 10GB (from the right).
- Move the SDA4 extended partition over to the left by 10GB.
- Move the SDA2 primary partition over to the left by 10GB.
- Stretch the SDA3 primary partition to the left, adding 10GB.
- Hit "Go".
- Wait until it's done.

Notes:

- There's ALWAYS a risk of partitions being corrupted when resizing and moving them (especially when doing multiple operations that take a lot of time), ensure you have a full (preferably image-style) backup of everything before you start.  It's big data moves on an intrinsic part of the file-system, and the slightest problem while it's happening can completely corrupt an entire partition.
- Performing all these actions could (most likely will) take MANY HOURS to complete, so don't be surprised if it takes overnight to complete fully.

Comment: I reached the end of the extended partition but now I can't move the System Reserved partition with "boot" flag. What Am I forgetting? (the unallocated space is in the following pic of 27.34Gib)

I think I cannot remove System Reserved Windows Partition because It contains boot data. I have GRUB installed, is there a workaround for this?

[Gparted Scheme](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/534/oamm.png)